# Want to use saveEventually() if save() not successful in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I need to save an object in parse. I want to use `save()` with timeout . If `save()` is not successful then it should use `saveEventually()`. Can I instead use `saveEventually()` with a timer if the timer expires before getting the callback from `saveEventually()` it should show a message.

```
userQuestions = new ParseObject("UserQuestions");
userQuestions.put("questionAsked", edt_askQuestion.getText().toString());
userQuestions.put("askedByUser", SignInActivity.pUser);
userQuestions.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {

        //cancel the timeout timer
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        Intent intent = new Intent(AActivity.this, DActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.Extras.INTENT_EXTRA_QUESTION, edt_askQuestion.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
//countdown timer for timeout
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {


    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        LogUtil.d("seconds remaining: ", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));

    }


    public void onFinish() {

        //if timer is triggered before saving object
        Toast.makeText(AActivity.this, "Problem with net connectivity question will be saved when net is connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}.start();
```

is this correct or is there any other way?

Comment: I do not get why you want to add a timeout. Then might as well use saveInBackground instead. The idea with saveeventually is not having to worry about when it is saved, you just know that it will.

Comment: just go with saveEventually(), it takes care of all.